# Inserting elements without affecting children (limit jQuery's selector's depth)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

Let's pretend I have the following DOM structure:

```
<li role="treeitem" aria-selected="false" aria-level="2" aria-labelledby="3_anchor" aria-expanded="true" id="3" class="jstree-node  jstree-open">
    <div unselectable="on" role="presentation" class="jstree-wholerow">&nbsp;</div>
    <i class="jstree-icon jstree-ocl" role="presentation"></i>
    <a class="jstree-anchor" href="#" tabindex="-1" id="3_anchor">
        <i class="jstree-icon jstree-themeicon" role="presentation"></i>Hombre (3)
    </a>
    <ul role="group" class="jstree-children">
        <li role="treeitem" aria-selected="false" aria-level="3" aria-labelledby="10_anchor" id="10" class="jstree-node  jstree-leaf">
            <div unselectable="on" role="presentation" class="jstree-wholerow">&nbsp;</div>
            <i class="jstree-icon jstree-ocl" role="presentation"></i>
            <a class="jstree-anchor" href="#" tabindex="-1" id="10_anchor">
                <i class="jstree-icon jstree-themeicon" role="presentation"></i>Corbatas (10)
            </a>
        </li>
        <li role="treeitem" aria-selected="false" aria-level="3" aria-labelledby="9_anchor" id="9" class="jstree-node  jstree-leaf jstree-last">
            <div unselectable="on" role="presentation" class="jstree-wholerow">&nbsp;</div>
            <i class="jstree-icon jstree-ocl" role="presentation"></i>
            <a class="jstree-anchor" href="#" tabindex="-1" id="9_anchor">
                <i class="jstree-icon jstree-themeicon" role="presentation"></i>Sudaderas (9)
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Now let's say I want to insert something after the `a` element of the most upper `li` item (that is, the `a` with the text `Hombre (3)`).

If I use

```
$("<i>").insertAfter('a', my_dom_element);
```

the `i` element will be inserted in every `a` element (3 in total), which is what I want to prevent.

How can I force jQuery to search only 1 level down in the DOM, instead of traversing all the elements?

I can't use any classes to limit the search, as I don't know what classes the DOM will have. I'm looking specifically for **limiting jQuery's levels of DOM scanning**

EDIT:

I'm pretty much looking for this: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/9391

Comment: You can do this `$("<i>").insertAfter('.jstree-node#3 > a', my_dom_element);`

Comment: "*One level down in the DOM*" from where..?

Comment: @anpsmn Thank you for reading my entire question...

Comment: @DavidThomas One level from the most upper `li` element

Comment: @alexandernst oh sorry, just missed that. How do you plan to add the element, on click?

Comment: @anpsmn I really don't think that matters. Maybe on click, maybe after some other event. Anyways, I see where are you going, but no, using some trickery with `e.target` (or similar) is a no-no.

Comment: @alexandernst ok, you can do this `$("<i>").insertAfter('li:eq(0) > a', my_dom_element);`

Comment: @anpsmn I  was already suggested that (twice, actually). Please have a look at the answers and my concerns about that solution.

Answer (score 3):

You can use attribute `aria-level` to target the li with value as 2. and then use immediate child selector to only target immediate anchor element:

```
$("<i>").insertAfter('li[aria-level="2"] > a', my_dom_element);
```

Update: without using classes,IDs, attributes etc.

```
$("<i>").insertAfter('a:first', my_dom_element);
```

or

```
$("<i>").insertAfter('a:eq(0)', my_dom_element);
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I can't use any classes, IDs, attributes, properties, texts or anything else. I specifically need to limit the depth of jQuery's selector.

Comment: @alexandernst: see the update. use `:eq(0)` or `:first`

Comment: Ok, this is getting me to somewhere. Not exactly what I was looking for, but it's a good starting point. Now, the problem with that is that if there are two `a` elements on the first level of `li`, this one will match only the first one. Any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: that is the reason you should use id ,class or attribute selector. you can use something like this `$("<i>").insertAfter($('li[aria-label='+$('a:eq(0)').parent().attr('aria-level')+'] >a'), my_dom_element)`. which is a terrible approach

Comment: I'd gladly use classes, attributes, or anything else, but I can't. I simply can't because I don't know what the DOM will look like.

Comment: Your code is still using attributes (`aria-level`). Please, I think what I'm saying is simple enough to understand: I can't use any classes, attributes, ids, or anything else. I need a DOM-depth limit.

Comment: which is not static. so it should not bother the approach. Try with `$("<i>").insertAfter($('a:eq(0)').parent().siblings().addBack().find('>a'), my_dom_element)`

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
$( "<i>" ).insertAfter( "a:first" , my_dom_element);
```

**UPDATE:**

For two a tags, i think you can do this:

```
$("<i>").insertAfter('a:eq(0),a:gt(0)', my_dom_element);
```

Comment: Ok, this is getting me to somewhere. Not exactly what I was looking for, but it's a good starting point. Now, the problem with that is that if there are two a elements on the first level of li, this one will match only the first one. Any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: Your first suggestion was smart. The second one however... What if I have 8 `a` elements? Or 20? I'm looking for something less.... rubbish...

Comment: @alexandernst how about now i have used `:gt` selector to select all other a tags except the first.

Comment: Yes, that would work. Still not the answer I was looking for, but it will do it.